# How to call accLocation() method of Win api using JNI to get caret position in windows?

Tags: java, .net, winapi, browser, java-native-interface

I want to call `accLocation()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318010.aspx method of winapi using JNI but I am not able to find out classes in JNI to call method.I want to call `accLocation()` to get caret position in any application in  windows like all browser also(as `GetGuiThreadInfo()` method is not working for chrome browser).

Solution will greatly appreciated.

Comment: `accLocation()` is a method of the IAccessible interface used by the (older) MSAA accessibility framework. To get an IAccessible, you will need to use one of the MSAA client APIs to get the IAccessible for a given window handle. I don't know how you would get the IAccessible for a caret; I'm sure the documentation would help... (The current standard is UI Automation, which is similar. MSAA and UI Automation proxy to each other [in a sense] so you can use either.)

Comment: Thanks andlabs for your reply.